# Fixing my Resume

Tags: resume, skills, transition

I'm currently fixing my resume just make it ready for the near future opportunities.
Here's my situation:

- The company I'm working in will be merging with another company, so this means that the company will be changing names. I Will be undergoing in-company transition, too
- I was promoted from "Computer Programmer" to "Computer Programmer I" within just a year
- I need to add specific skills to my chosen programming language

The questions are:

- How should indicate in my resume that I worked and got promoted in a single company that changed its name recently?
- How should I add specific skills like 'Deep understanding Object Oriented Programming', 'Knows SOLID and N-Tier Architecture', etc.?

In my country some companies are searching for potential candidates that knows these specific skills in a chosen programming language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning the company name, you can simply do something like

> Comany X (formerly Y, Inc).

Your titles are *very* similar, so I'd just mention the latter but mention in the description of the job that you were originally hired as *A* but you got promoted to *B* after *Z* amount of time.

It's good to have a general skill set category but also to have a very specific one that covers very rock solid terms.

I recommend looking at others' resumes, from people in your field, to get a better idea. Also, resume structure has been covered a lot on this site.